# Show PlaceholderText Color of ComboBox in WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to ask you what should i do to show placeholderText of ComboBox On White Background Grid.

```
 <Grid Background="White">
    <ComboBox Name="CityCombobox"   BorderThickness="0"  Grid.Column="1" PlaceholderText="Select Item">
        <ComboBoxItem>Chandigarh</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Delhi</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Sirsa</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I do believe that is exactly how you are supposed to be doing it. Are you experiencing  any problems with it?

Comment: Due to white background i can't see the placeholderText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
            <ComboBox SelectionChanged="City_SelectionChanged" Name="CityCombobox" RequestedTheme="Light" BorderThickness="0" Tapped="CitySelection_Tapped" Grid.Column="1" PlaceholderText="Select City">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding City.city}" Style="{StaticResource PageTextStyle}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Here requested theme sets the light theme for control which shows placeholder text even in white background. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously because you make the background white, and the placeholder color is also white (when the phone background color is black), you are not able to see the placeholder. What you could do is just not set the background color to white as the defaults of Windows Phone will have it black or white and it will make sure the placeholder color is visible.

Else you will need to override te color of the placeholder. You can do this in two ways.

1. Globally: this will override all the colors of the placeholders in you entire application. You can do this like so in your app.xaml

`<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush" Color="#ff000000" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>`

2. override the style of the object. When you add the element in your xaml. right click it in the designer. there you can choose to copy the style. Place this in a document. find the `TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush` and give it your value. then give the element in your xaml this particular style